# Table with multiple relations to a single primary key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to create multiple relations from one table, to another table?

I have a table containing purchases, each of these purchases have a origin_country and a destination_country.
I would like to have relations (as foreign keys) to a single PK on a table from these two columns from the same table.

[image: Image of the relation I want to create]

i have tried the following queries:

```
alter table Purchases
    add constraint FK_Purchases_OriginCountries
        foreign key (FK_OriginCountryCode) references dbo.countries

go

alter table Purchases
    add constraint FK_Purchases_DestinationCountries
        foreign key (FK_DestinationCountryCode) references dbo.countries
    
go
```

But end up getting a conflict, I can't however find documentation that this is not possible...

> [23000][547] The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
> constraint "FK_Purchases_DestinationCountries". The conflict occurred
> in database "Market", table "dbo.countries", column 'ID'.

Is this relationship intentionally not possible, or did i just make a mistake?

Thank you

Comment: You jump to the wrong conclusion. You have bad data - as already indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

The error is not a result of trying to create two foreign keys back to a single table, that's perfectly fine. Try running this to see it work:

```
create table t(i int primary key);

create table u
(
   j int foreign key references t(i),
   k int foreign key references t(i)
);
```

The problem you have is that you have some data in your `Purchases` table where the value in the column on which you are trying to create the foreign key does not exist in the `countries` table's `ID` column.

To find them run a query like this:

```
select  p.* 
from    dbo.purchases p 
where   not exists 
        (
           select *
           from   dbo.countries
           where  ID = p.FK_DestinationCountryCode
        )
```

Note that I think your column names are a little weird here, You shouldn't call a column `FK_DestinationCountryCode` just because it has a foreign key on it, and a "code" is not the same kind of thing as an "ID". Your `purchases` table's columns should probably be called `DestinationCountryID` and `OriginCountryID`.

Comment: Ah thats great! I am meant to clean up this database, and add foreign keys, I was told that adding FK_ would make the keys stand out when looking from an BI perspective :)

Comment: @LauritsBertelsen That's sort of the same as saying that every table should be prefixed with `Tbl`, and every column should be prefixed with `Col`. The implementation details behind the schema shouldn't be part of the semantic names of the schema. The fact that the column would be called `OriginCountryID` is enough of a hint that it is referencing another table. If someone really wants to see the keys, they can look at a diagram, or read the system metadata, or any of several other methods.

Comment: I felt like I was missing something, since SSMS names fk relations as "FK_tableA_tableB" - it seems a bit redundant to declare this here, thank you for pointing it out :-)

Comment: @LauritsBertelsen No worries, if you have any other issue with this let me know, otherwise please accept the answer (click the big tick) - both because it gives me a few fake internet points (yay points), and also because it lets other people on the site know that you're not still waiting for an answer to your question.